# Increment number that part of string using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to search number with specific format from string and increment the last number by 1 using powershell. The string is taken from large txt file.

Example:

```
$str = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0200, Prod 3.4.0104"
```

I want to increase beta version by 1 (`2.0.0200` ==> `2.0.0201`),

After run powershell command:

```
$str = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0201, Prod 3.4.0104"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit clunky, but seems to work:

```
$str = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0201, Prod 3.4.0104"

if($str -match "(?<=Beta = \d+\.\d+\.)(?<bv>\d+)")
{
    $str -replace "(?<=Beta = \d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)", ("{0:0000}" -f (([int]::Parse($matches.bv)+1)))
}
```

There might be a way to get it to work in one line with just the `-Replace`, but it eludes me for the moment.

Comment: I fail to understand the desire that people have to force a one line solution. I often feel it obfuscates what the code is doing for no real gain. This is not a criticism of your answer by the way. It is perfectly valid. Just an observation of a trend that I actually find to be detrimental. Especially for people that are new to a language.

Comment: @EBGreen.  I totally agree.  My comment wasn't worded correctly - normally, I'd not try to force a 1-liner, but in this case `-replace` allows you to reference matches (`$1`, `${name}`, etc), which would be much neater without obfuscation - I just couldn't make it work :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The idea isn't to write it in 1 line. I just want to know how to write this in clean way....

Comment: I feel that one liners should stay in the command line. If you are going to put your scripting logic in a file go ahead and write the verbose version for readability.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `version` type in powershell you can take advantage of like so. The following will output a the beta version string incremented.

```
$originalString = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0200, 
Prod 3.4.0104"

$parsedString = $originalString.Split(' ')
$betaVersionStr = $parsedString[8].TrimEnd(',')
$betaVersion = [version]$betaVersionStr

# you can always condense those lines above if you want
# $betaVersion = [version]$originalString.Split(' ')[8].TrimEnd(',')

"{0}.{1}.{2:d4}" -f $betaVersion.Major, $betaVersion.Minor, ($betaVersion.Build + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer will depend a lot on how representative your example is of the rest of your actual data, but for the example you gave:

```
$str = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0200, Prod 3.4.0104"
$str -match ('^(.+), (Beta = )(.+),(.+)$')
$ver = $matches[3].split('.')
$ver[2] = '{0:0000}' -f ([int]$ver[2] + 1)
$newVerStr = $ver -join '.'
$newStr = '{0}, {1}{2},{3}' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $newVerStr, $matches[4]
$newStr
```

Comment: There are cleaner ways to do that regex. I'll edit if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet using the method Replace of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex:

```
$str = "Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0200, Prod 3.4.0104"
[regex]::Replace($str, '(?<Head>.+\.)(?<Beta>\d+)(?<Tail>,[^,]+)$',
  { param( [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]$m )
    $bv = 1 + $m.Groups['Beta'].Value
    '{0}{1:0000}{2}' -f $m.Groups['Head'].Value,$bv,$m.Groups['Tail'].Value
  }
)
```

The output:

`Android version 4.4.2, Alfa = 1.2.0400, Beta = 2.0.0201, Prod 3.4.0104`